# Anaconda: Installing package raises UnsatisfiableError on itself

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to build a new conda package. I used conda skeleton to create a meta.yaml file which I edited to my needs:

```
package:
   name: ofl
   version: "master"

source:
    git_url: git@github.com:fergalm/Fireworks.git
    git_tag: master

build:
  # noarch: python
  # preserve_egg_dir: True

entry_points:
    # Put any entry points (scripts to be generated automatically) here. The
    # syntax is module:function.  For example
    #
    # - pyinstrument = pyinstrument:main
    #
    # Would create an entry point called pyinstrument that calls  pyinstrument.main()

  # If this is a new build for the same version, increment the build
  # number. If you do not include this key, it defaults to 0.
  # number: 1

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - boto3
    - yaml
    - dateutil
```

I can build this package with `conda-build ofl`, but when I try to install it with `conda install ofl --use-local` I get the following error

```
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - ofl
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What does it mean for my package, ofl, to be in conflict with itself? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You have a number of YAML errors in that meta.yaml file - the `build` and `entry_point` sections are empty, to start, and the three dots to end the file should not be indented. Once those are fixed, I can't access that git url, so you should change it to https, at least for this example. I also had to delete git as a buildtime dependency because of a missing shared library on my system (but that might be my system) Finally, with `conda-build` v3.0.14, it says there's an error with your runtime specifications, because `dateutil` is only available for Python 2.6. I'm not sure how you built this

Comment: It's my first time, so bear with me. My goal is to have conda install all the dependencies for this repo (I'd forgotten that it's private, I'll switch the url to something public for the example. I don't actually want to build anything, just install all the dependencies so I can proceed to develop the code, so I didn't fill in any build or entry points (if that's a mistake, let me know). The three dots at the end were just to indicate that there are more dependencies in the yaml file not included above (about 80 total). I'm using conda-build version 2.1.17, and python 2.7.13

Comment: If you just want to install the dependencies, you should put them in an `environment.yml` file and install with `conda install --file environment.yml`.  Conda build is for, well, building conda packages. The format of the `environment.yml` file can be found here: https://github.com/binder-project/example-conda-environment/blob/master/environment.yml

Comment: I had the same realisation this morning. I'm doing this all wrong. Thanks for your help.